# Can I print the whole array without getting 'Cannot read field "value" because "anotherInteger" is null' error?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, integer

Well I am trying to create a program that is going to print number is decending number usings `rays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());` method.

it's giving me an error. because some of the values of the array is NULL.
error msg -`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "value" because "anotherInteger" is null`

Example: If I put `5` as the value of `number`, then only the first 5 elements of that array is going to have a value. So, it's showing me an error.

and here is the code

```
            int number = sc.nextInt();
            Integer array[]= new Integer[10];
            for(int j=0;j<number;j++){  // here number is the number of inputs,
                    array[j]= sc.nextInt();
            }
            Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder()); // to sort our array
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

now, is there any way that I can print the whole array without getting the error message?

Comment: Well why have you created an array of size `10` if you're going to fill `number` elements? Why not create an array of `number` elements? (Your current code would fail in a different way if someone entered 11 to start with, aside from anything else...)

Comment: Thanks man, didnt think about that. Thank you @JonSkeet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
int numbersAmount = sc.nextInt();
Integer[] array = new Integer[numbersAmount];
for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
    array[j] = sc.nextInt();
}
Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

**Additionally:**

Think about:

- What if you press ENTER without any Input?
- What If you press ENTER If the input is an alphabetic letter?